# my trigger in the dbms mysql does'nt work

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to write an after trigger in mysql dbms but it does'nt work.the goal is to delete all rows except the most recent one (the one in the row that is inserted) after an insert event.Please where is my error?

```
BEGIN 

DECLARE num integer;
DECLARE num2 integer;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num FROM TABLENAME;
SELECT MAX(temps) INTO num2 FROM TABLENAME;

    IF num > 3 THEN

        DELETE FROM TABLENAME WHERE temps < num2;

    END IF;

END
```

Comment: Where is the CREATE TRIGGER?

Comment: Have a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: @Donald In the version of mysql that i'm using,i don't need to write this part of the code.i just set the cases (trigger name,table,moment,event).I just have to write the BEGIN PART.